# List Index Out of Range Python - Begginer

Tags: python

I tried to limit the range "i" could go to with:

```
while i < len(words) - 1
```

But this doesn't look to get my problem fixed since I get the error:

```
in corta_texto
    while size + len(words[i]) + len(phrase_line) - 1 < maxlength:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't quite get it to work as I've tried to poke here and there to fix it.
Im quite new to python and asking here would be my last resource because this is a school project but I really can't seem to get this to work.

Here's the code so far:

```
def corta_texto(phrase, maxlength):

    words = phrase.split()
    phrase_tuple = []
    phrase_line = ''
    size = 0
    i = 0

    while i < len(words) - 1:
        while size + len(words[i]) + len(phrase_line) - 1 < maxlength:

            size += len(words[i]) + len(phrase_tuple) - 1
            phrase_line += words[i] + ' '
            i += 1
        else:
            phrase_tuple.append(phrase_line)
            phrase_line = ''
            i += 1
            size = 0

    return phrase_tuple
```

I've tried
I've looked for other questions like this but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to the Financial Information Exchange Protocol? Why did you add that tag?

Comment: Your `i += 1` increases value of `i` **inside** your loop.

Comment: Don't use `while i < len(words) - 1`. Use `for word in words:`

Comment: I believe your inner `while` should have said `if`. And `len(phrase_tuple)` should have said `len(phrase_line)`. And your `size` calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you should use the 'in' statement for lists, arrays, etc.

```
words = ['word', 'word2', 'word3']
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
word
word2
word3
```